# How to rename the specific pattern in the column name?

Tags: r

I'd like to rename a value with a specific pattern in the column name. 
For example,

```r
ex_before<-data.frame(A1B..123.=c('a', 'b', 'c'), 
               BCD43..24.=c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
               Q2E4W..532.=c(1,4,2),
               OI95J8..934.=c(9,3,9))
ex_before
  A1B..123. BCD43..24. Q2E4W..532. OI95J8..934.
1        a        d         1         9
2        b        e         4         3
3        c        f         2         9

ex_after<-data.frame('123'=c('a', 'b', 'c'), 
               '24'=c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
               '532'=c(1,4,2),
               '934'=c(9,3,9))
names(ex_after)<-gsub(x=names(ex_after), pattern="X", replacement="")
ex_after
  123 24 532 934
1   a  d   1   9
2   b  e   4   3
3   c  f   2   9
```

I tried the stupid method like below, but I guess that there must be a more efficient method.

```r
names(ex_before)<-gsub(x=names(ex_before), pattern="\\w+\\..", replacement="")
names(ex_before)<-gsub(x=names(ex_before), pattern="\\.", replacement="")

ex_before
  123 24 532 934
1   a  d   1   9
2   b  e   4   3
3   c  f   2   9
```

Can anyone suggest other approach?

Comment: `gsub("\\D", "", names(ex_before))`?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comment! Can you check the other case in my question? I modified the column names.

Comment: So, in words, you want the new column name to be the last consecutive string of digits in the old column name? Is it always of the form `"*****d."` where `*` can be anything, `d` is one or more digits, and there is a literal `.` at the end?

Comment: If you don't mind extra packages, `stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(names(ex_before), "\\d+")`

Comment: `gsub(".*\\..*?([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$", "\\1", nms)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for comment! Although I didn't explain about the detail description about the property of column, each column name has Gene name(=symbol) and its' ID. The original format was symbol(ID) such as A1BG(1), MED18(54797), r automatically changed '(' and ')' to '..' and '.' . So MED18(54797) goes to MED18..54797. form. In this case, I want to change the column names to ID.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! It works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
names(ex_before) <- sub('.*\\.(\\d+)\\.$', '\\1', names(ex_before))
ex_before

#  123 24 532 934
#1   a  d   1   9
#2   b  e   4   3
#3   c  f   2   9
```

This basically extracts the number which are between periods (`"."`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works well, too. Thank you so much!